# For distinct $A$ and $B$, show that $R_{b,180^\circ}\circ\rho_{AB}\circ R_{b,180^\circ}$ is a glide reflection, and find its axis.

Tags: geometry

> Let $A$ and $B$ be any two distinct points. Prove that the composition $R_{b,180^\circ}\circ \rho_{AB} \circ R_{b,180^\circ}$ is a glide reflection and find its axis.

[original problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2kY7.jpg)

I am confused how to write the proof but i can visually understand it in my head.

Comment: To be clear: $R_{P,\theta}$ represents rotation about $P$ through angle $\theta$, and $\rho_{PQ}$ is reflection in $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$, correct?

Comment: Please tell us what you know about the problem. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Specifically: What do you know about classifying transformations (in terms of, say, fixed elements and/or preserving orientation)? This information can help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) [Edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3450727/edit) to add details.